# spyder 3.1.2 python 3.6 does not import igraph

Tags: python-3.x, igraph, spyder

Hallo I am using spyder 3.1.2. I successfully installed python-igraph 0.7.1.post36 ad python-igraph via anaconda prompt but spyder cannot import it and gives the message:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'igraph'

and when I try to install pycairo‑1.10.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl it says it is not supported on that platform.
I am using windows 10.
Thank you so much for any help
tiziana

Comment: I update my problem: it seemed the packages are available for python 3.5 but not 3.6. So I created a virtual environment running python 3.5.3 (verified: python --version). I can install  igraph and pycairo.It all works under Ipython but spyder 3, called from virtual environment  running pthon 3.5.3 still cannot import: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'igraph'.My virtual environment is active and the installation is recognized as successful: from anaconda cloud I installed -igraph=0.7.1.post7 and the console says:# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment.Thanks